# Concat columns adding data in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, date

I am getting some data from database that has date break up in year month and year due to some reason i want to concat the column and add a new column.

What i  am doing is adding the data

```
                    DataColumn newColumn;
                    newColumn = new DataColumn("CompositeDate");
                    newColumn.Expression = "Day + Month + Year" ;
                    scaleResponseData.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

the data in the data table  is some thing like this

```
year | Month | Day
2009   10       2
2010   11       3
```

What my current code is doing

```
year | Month | Day | composite_Date 
2009   10       2      2021
2010   11       3      2024
```

But the result should be some thing

```
year | Month | Day | composite_Date 
 2009   10     02      20091002
 2010   11     03      20101103
```

I have different combination but nothing is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
newColumn.Expression = "Convert(Day , 'System.String') + Convert(Month , 'System.String') + Convert(Year, 'System.String')";
```

Comment: it is working but a slight thing is missing i am using the column in my expression                                              scaleID=105 and CompositeDate Between '3/1/2009 6:01:23 PM' And '5/31/2009 6:01:23 PM'                                                                  that is above written i am getting an error The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your columns are numbers and adding three numbers will yield a new number.

Try to force the expression to make a string by including an empty text between the columns:

```
newColumn.Expression = "Day + '' + Month + '' + Year" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yoo can also convert that to "real" DateTime type, like this.

```
newColumn.Expression = "Convert(Year + '/' + Month + '/' + Day, 'System.DateTime')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have year, month and date as ints in database they are added numerically, say:
Year = 2009, month = 10 and day = 2 == 2009+10+2 = 2021, which is your current composite_date.

You should probably try 
year * 10000 + month * 100 + day to get the result you desire =>  `newColumn.Expression = "Day + Month * 100 +  Year * 10000" ;`